# How to to properly use the fopen command in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program that asks a user to input the file name they wish to open and then using it to open the file as per user input.

Below is what I have so far. (Keep in mind that this is intro to C language):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main (void)

{
FILE *data_File;
char fileName[6];
int ecoli_lvl;
printf ("Which month would you like a summary of? \nType month followed by date (i.e: july05): ");
scanf ("%lf", &fileName);
data_File = fopen (fileName, "r");
fscanf (data_File, "%d", &ecoli_lvl);
printf ("%d", ecoli_lvl);
return (0);
}
```

The data in the text file is all integers as below:

1 101 5 66.6 33.3 22.2 98.9 11.1

5 501 2 33.3 44.3

And yet what the program prints is dependent on the number I put in the square brackets for char fileName[x] (I thought the x signifies that length in characters for what the user will input. How to I code the above properly so that it prints all the numbers I have in the file?

Thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: `%lf` isn't going to bode well if you're trying to read a *string*. [some documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors to fix:

1. Size of the array for file name.

   ```
   char fileName[6];
   ```

   This can hold a file name that is at most 5 characters long. Make the array size bigger.

   ```
   char fileName[200]; // Hopefully that is sufficient.
   ```
2. Reading the name of the file.

   ```
   scanf ("%lf", &fileName);
   ```

   `%lf` is the wrong format to use for reading strings. Also, you don't need `&fileName`. Just `fileName` is the right thing to use.

   ```
   scanf ("%199s", fileName);  // Make sure that format also
                               // specifies the maximum number
                               // of characters that should be read
                               // in to fileName.
   ```
3. Check the return value of `fopen` before using it.

   ```
   data_File = fopen (fileName, "r");
   if ( data_File != NULL )
   {
      fscanf (data_File, "%d", &ecoli_lvl);
   }
   ```

Comment: not only do you not 'need &fileName', you really don't want it.  That will cause scanf to overwrite the address of the filename array, rather than the contents.

Comment: @Arunas, when you have an array, `&fileName` is the same as `&fileName[0]`, which is what `fileName` decays to. Hence, `&fileName` also works but only when it is an array. If it is a pointer, then `&fileName` will be wrong.

Comment: Is the .txt file in question supposed to be in a specific place. So far I have it on my documents which is the same place as the directory the Quincy software (its what i'm using) takes me when I manually click on the open button. I've tried the above steps but the code does not output anything so far. Thanks again

Comment: @EnxhK, The name of the file has to be (a) relative to the directory where you run the program is run, or (b) absolute path.

Comment: @RSahu so if my program is saved on the same directory as the .txt file then I shouldn't have any problems right? If that's the case I'm still not able to read the .txt file. Do you have to specify in the code that the file to read is a .txt file? Also, would it be better if I put all the project's file under one folder and try it again? Thanks a lot man.

Comment: @EnxhK, no. The program can reside in "dir1" but if the program is run in "dir2", then the file name has to be specified relative to "dir2".

Comment: @RSahu how would I know on which directory it's running? How would I fix this issue?

Comment: @EnxhK, what's your platform? How are you executing the program?

Comment: @RSahu Win7. I'm using Quincy 2005. Basically when the program is asking me which month to open i type "july08" and i've named the .txt file exactly that but nothing shows up:

  if (data_File != NULL)
  {
 fscanf (data_File, "%d", &ecoli_lvl);
 printf ("%d", ecoli_lvl);
 }
 else 
 printf ("no file was found");

Comment: @EnxhK, First of all, I have never used Quincy 2005. There might be a setting somewhere that tells the directory from where the program is being run. Second -- is your file named "july08.txt" or just "july08". You need to give the exact name of the file.

Comment: @RSahu the file is named july08. I've tried changing the file name to july08.txt but nothing. I'm also trying to print the 'filename' so that I make sure the code is actually picking up whatever I input but even that is not showing.

Comment: @EnxhK, You can try the absolute path name. Other than that I don't know what else to say to help you.

Comment: @RSahu wow.  Thanks for pointing that one out.  I've been using c/c++ for over 20 years and never knew that the address of operator behaves like that on an array, probably because I've just assumed that it's not what I want.  It still would be a bad idea to use it, because as soon as you decide to dynamically allocate enough space rather than hoping that the 256 character space is enough, the & operator won't be  a NOP  anymore.

Comment: @RSahu your code was right. The reason it wasn't working is because when the user is asked to type the name of the file they HAVE to type the 'name of the file.txt' and the actual file should be named just 'name of the file' without the need of the .txt. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks like floating point inputs to me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE  *data_File;
  char   fileName[256] = { 0 };
  double ecoli_lvl;

  while (1)
  {
    printf("Of which month would you like a summary?\nType month followed by date (i.e: july05): ");
    fflush(stdout);

    scanf("%255s", fileName);

    if (NULL != (data_File = fopen(fileName, "r")))
      break;

    perror("Couldn't open file!");
  }

  while (1 == fscanf(data_File, "%lf", &ecoli_lvl))
    printf("%lf ", ecoli_lvl);

  printf("\n");
  fclose(data_File);

  return (0);
}
```